# Unable to use dojox.editor.plugins.AutoUrlLink

Tags: plugins, dojo, editor

I am using dijit/Editor in my application and I would like to use the autourllink plugin as I want users to click directly on the hyperlink in the editor and have the page open up.

The example listed on their website is not working:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/editor/plugins/AutoUrlLink.html#dojox-editor-plugins-autourllink

And, after downloading Dojo and trying it out, I receive the following error:

```
AutoUrlLink.js:169 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'previousSibling' of null
    at Object._findLastEditingNode (AutoUrlLink.js:169)
    at Object._recognize (AutoUrlLink.js:77)
    at Object.<anonymous> (lang.js:383)
    at Object.dispatcher [as onClick] (aspect.js:101)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (lang.js:383)
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
var myEditor = new Editor({
                plugins: ['cut','copy','paste','|','bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','subscript','superscript','|', 'indent', 'outdent', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight'],
                extraPlugins: [AlwaysShowToolbar, 'createLink', 'autourllink']
            }, parentNode);
myEditor.startup();
```

Any help on using this plugin would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code that you have written so far, please?

Comment: Updated the post with code snippet.